# Security Login in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, login

I want to know if exists some way to login in Windows with a Security pendrive...without the use of a password... I heard about the Security Card... How it works? Any relative ideas are welcome... I already tried to search about it, and I only find about Fingerprint machines... but I want to know if exists other simmilar ways to login...

Comment: Are you trying to do 2 factor security or just trying not to remember a password or thinking a password isn't secure enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Windows PKI USB Token, such as one of [these](http://www.safenet-inc.com/multi-factor-authentication/authenticators/pki-usb-authentication/). They usually range in the multiple 100$, but less than 1000$. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.08.howitworks.aspx) is more information on PKI and how it works.